# How do I finish off this WebScrape code to get just the title of the movie?

Tags: python, web-scraping

My output gives me the line with the movie title in but how do I simply pull out the movies title as a string. 
I have added the output at the bottom.

thanks

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import os
from datetime import datetime
import time

tstart = datetime.now()
myList = ["https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083944/",
          "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0377092/"]


for x in myList:

    page = requests.get(x)
    response = page.status_code
    if response == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
        genreData = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"subtext"})
        filmtitle = soup.find("h1")
        print(filmtitle)
        links = []
        for h in genreData:
            a = h.find_all('a')
            aLength = len(a) - 1
            a1 = a[0]
            for b in range(0,aLength):
                print(a[b].string)
```

```
<h1 class="">First Blood <span id="titleYear">(<a href="/year/1982/">1982</a>)</span> </h1>
Action
Adventure
<h1 class="">Mean Girls <span id="titleYear">(<a href="/year/2004/">2004</a>)</span> </h1>
Comedy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the HTML item nicely.  Now, you can get the contents of it as such:

```
In [47]: t = soup.find('h1')                                                   

In [48]: t.contents                                                            
Out[48]: 
['Mean Girls\xa0',
 <span id="titleYear">(<a href="/year/2004/">2004</a>)</span>,
 ' ']

In [49]: t.contents[0]                                                         
Out[49]: 'Mean Girls\xa0'

In [50]: t.contents[0].strip()   #strip() removes whitespace and breaks etc.                                              
Out[50]: 'Mean Girls'
```

Comment: Your code seems to work without the last part. t.contents[0] doesn't seem to give me "Mean Girls\xa0" but simply "Mean Girls".

Comment: Great.  depending on what you are doing, you may/may not need strip().  If it works for you, pls "accept the answer."

Answer (score 0):

you could have used the `data-title` attribute

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

my_list = ["https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083944/", "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0377092/"]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for link in my_list:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        print(soup.select_one('[data-title]')['data-title'])
```